# change images on click

Tags: jquery, fade

I found this code but I dont want to change by random.
I dont know how to change images by order.
Please help me!

HTML

```
 <div class=change><img id=bg src="items/01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

JQUERY :

```
var images = ["02.jpg","03.jpg","01.jpg"];

$(function() {
    $('.change').click(function(e) {
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `index` incremented by 1 instead of random. `Reset` index when it reaches array length.

```
var images = ["02.jpg","03.jpg","01.jpg"];

$(function() {
    index = 0;
    $('.change').click(function(e) {
    var image = images[index++];
    if(index == images.length) 
       index = 0;
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ["01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg"];
var currentimg = 0; 

$(function() {
    $('.change').click(function(e) {

        var image = images[currentimg];
        currentimg++;
        if(currentimg > 2){
            currentimg = 0;
        }

        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image); 
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
      });
    });
});
```

Try this. This should work for you.