# Change images randomly on click without repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this code on Stack Overflow: [change images on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241438/change-images-on-click).

And it works for me. I want it to be random, but how can i prevent it from repeating the images. It should first repeat the images, when the user has clicked through all images.

I have made an JSfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gr3f4hp1/

JQuery code:

```
var images = ["02.jpg","03.jpg","01.jpg"];

$(function() {
    $('.change').click(function(e) {
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the numbers that you have generated, and if its a repeat then get a new number.

You can Work Around This

```
var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        usedImagesCount++;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not the best at JQuery, so how do i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code .

```
var images = ["02.jpg","03.jpg","01.jpg"];
    var imagecon = [];
    $(function() {
        $('.change').click(function(e) {
            if(images.length == 0) { // if no image left
                images = imagecon; // put all used image back
                imagecon = []; // empty the container
            }
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
            var image = images[index];
            imagecon.push(image); // add used image
            images.splice(index,1); // remove it to images
            $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
                $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image);
                $(this).fadeIn(200);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it doesn't seem like it's working.

Comment: try to alert(image) or console.log(image) . it will show you the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a class to every image that appears like:

```
image.addClass("viewed")
```

and write an if statement that show the image only if it hasn't the class viewed:

```
if(!image.hasClass(viewed)){
    (show the image methods);
    image.addClass("viewed") 
}
```

I'm not going to make all the code for you, just try this way, learn, fail, success, have fun! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this  image change according to imgCnt variable.

```
var images = ["01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","01.jpg"];
    var imgCnt=1;
    $(function() {
        $('.change').click(function(e) {
       // var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
            if(imgCnt >= images.length){
             imgCnt=0;   
            }
           var image =images[imgCnt];
           // alert(image);
            $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
                $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image); 
                  $(this).fadeIn(200);
                imgCnt++;
            });
        });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tz2wL6sb/)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of method here i just push the value of visited image in to Visited array

Campate two array show only differ element

```
var images = ["02.jpg","03.jpg","01.jpg"];
var visited = [];
$(function() {
    $('.change').click(function(e) {
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
visited.push(image);
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {

 y = jQuery.grep(images, function(value) {
if(jQuery.inArray(value, visited) == -1){
     $('#bg').attr('src', 'items/'+image); 

              $(this).fadeIn(200);
  }
});

     }   });
    });
});
```

I hopes its help